# Office365 Audit Log

Tags: office365

We have Office365 E3 and know the 90 day history restriction. Go forward we may use AdminTool or a script to log and build our own database. However is there a way to access a longer history because we wish to inspect the log for previous months (say 2 years ago) and my question is broken into three parts:

- Is it possible irrespective of cost (we ring and pay
  Microsoft)?
- If it possible how would we do it given we have E3?
- Is there a smarter way (if the above aren't
  available) to discover if a user accessed material 6 months ago if we
  have E3?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need all the audit logs and keep it for a more extended period, then it's good to rely on [AdminDroid Office 365 Reporter Tool](https://admindroid.com) You shall retrieve past 365 days audit data if you have E5 or E3 with Advanced Compliance addon license.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Search the audit log in the Security & Compliance Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance):

> Office 365 E5 - Audit records are retained for 365 days (one year).
>   That means you can search the audit log for activities that were
>   performed within the last year. Retaining audit records for one year
>   is also available for users that are assigned an E3/Exchange Online
>   Plan 1 license and have an Office 365 Advanced Compliance add-on
>   license.

Adding those licenses will increase the retention time for current logs, but won't magically provide more data from before the current retention period of 90 days.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So that's a go forward solution. What about "emergency" historical?